# How to set up twitter open source mysql file after getting it from Github?

Tags: mysql, twitter, open-source, github

Another noob question. I downloaded the open source mysql file from this link: https://github.com/twitter/mysql. After that, I have no clue how I set it up. I have Wamp installed in my PC. I'm trying to study the twitter mysql tables from the file. Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That doesn't contain the tables used by Twitter; it contains a modified version of the mySQL server used by Twitter.

If you want to use it, you will need to build it from source.
However, as the `README` very clearly states, you should not use it.